# Change color of sticky menu when scrolled

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

Am editing a client's website and one thing has got my head spinning.

I would like to change the color of the sticky menu once it is scrolled. Can someone help me with a custom css to make those changes?

Here is my css

```
/*
Theme Name: Malory
Theme URI: http://www.tommusrhodus.com
Version: 1.0.3
Description: Malory - A Multipurpose, Responsive WordPress Theme.
Author: Tom Rhodes
Author URI: http://www.tommusrhodus.com
License: GNU General Public License version 3.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
Tags: white, custom-background, threaded-comments, translation-ready, custom-menu
*/

/* 

WARNING! DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!

To make it easy to update your theme, you should not edit the styles in this file. Instead use 
the custom.css file to add your styles. You can copy a style from this file and paste it in 
custom.css and it will override the style in this file. You have been warned! :)

*/



  /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Visual Composer Styles
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .vc_column_container > .vc_column-inner {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    .wpb_row {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .box {
        width: 100%;
    }
    div[data-vc-parallax] .box,
    div[data-vc-parallax-image] .box {
        background: none;
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Theme Styles
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .admin-bar .navbar.fixed,
    .admin-bar .slide-nav-container header,
    .admin-bar .lg-toolbar {
        top: 32px;
    }
    p:empty {
        display: none;
    }
    .feature {
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
        background: none;
    }
    .social.bordered .goodshare:before {
        display: none;
    }
    .social.bordered .goodshare {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .single-portfolio.admin-bar .fotorama {
        position: relative;
        top: -32px;
    }
    .admin-bar .slide-nav-wrapper {
        padding-top: 32px;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .tiles img {
        max-width: none;
    }
    .select-wrap {
        position: relative;
    }
    .select-wrap > span {
        position: absolute;
        right: 23px;
        top: 7px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    footer select {
        border-color: #ccc;
    }
    footer address {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  WORDPRESS DEFAULT STYLES
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .post-content ul, .post-content ol,
    .wpb_text_column ul,
    .wpb_text_column ol {
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-position: inside;
    }
    .post-content ul ul, .post-content ol ol,
    .wpb_text_column ul ul, .wpb_text_column ol ol {
        margin: 0 0 0 40px;
    }
    .sticky {
    }
    .bypostauthor img.avatar {
    }
    .screen-reader-text {
    }
    select {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .alignleft,
    .aligncenter,
    .alignright,
    .alignnone {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .alignnone {
        display: block;
    }
    .alignleft { 
        float: left; 
        margin: 0 30px 30px 0 !important;
    }
    .alignright { 
        float: right; 
        margin: 0 0 30px 30px !important;
    }
    .aligncenter { 
        display: block; 
        margin-right: auto; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        text-align: center; 
    }
    figure.aligncenter a {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    .wp-caption { 
        max-width: 100%; 
        text-align: center; 
    }
    .wp-caption img {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .gallery-caption { 
        margin: 20px 0; 
        max-width: 100%; 
        text-align: center; 
        z-index: 999; 
    }
    .wp-caption-text, 
    .gallery-caption-text { 
        margin: 6px 0; 
        font-style: italic; 
        font-size: 95%; 
        line-height: 120%; 
    }
    .aligncenter { 
        text-align: center;
    }
    table#wp-calendar {
        border: 1px solid #cccccc
    }
    table#wp-calendar>tbody>tr>td>a {
        text-decoration: underline
    }
    table#wp-calendar thead>tr>th { 
        width: 35px;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }
    table#wp-calendar tbody>tr>td {
        width: 35px;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }
    table#wp-calendar tfoot>tr>td>a, 
    tfoot>tr>td>a:link, 
    tfoot>tr>td>a:visited, 
    tfoot>tr>td>a:hover, 
    tfoot>tr>td>a:active {
        text-decoration: underline;
        height: 23px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
    table#wp-calendar tfoot>tr>td#prev {
        width: 58px;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    table#wp-calendar tfoot>tr>td#next {
        width: 58px;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .post-content table,
    .wpb_text_column table {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .post-content table tr,
    .post-content table td,
    #wp-calendar table tr,
    #wp-calendar table td,
    .wpb_text_column tr,
    .wpb_text_column td {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }
    dd {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    dt {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .widget_rss li {
        margin-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .widget_rss li .rsswidget, .widget_rss li cite {
        font-weight: bold; display: block;
    }
    .widget_rss li .rss-date {
        display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .widget_rss li cite {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .post-content hr,
    .wpb_text_column hr {
        clear: both;
    }
    .post-content span.pull-right,
    .post-content span.pull-left,
    .wpb_text_column span.pull-right,
    .wpb_text_column span.pull-left {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    .post-content span.pull-right,
    .wpb_text_column span.pull-right {
        float: right;
        margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .post-content span.pull-left,
    .wpb_text_column span.pull-left {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    }
    .post-content table,
    .wpb_text_column table {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .post-content table td,
    .post-content table th,
    .wpb_text_column table td,
    .wpb_text_column table th {
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .post-content table tr:nth-child(even),
    .post-content table thead tr,
    .wpb_text_column table thead tr,
    .wpb_text_column table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f5f5f5;
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  CONTACT FORM 7
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    div.wpcf7 .wpcf7-not-valid { 
        border: 2px solid #b54d4d
    }
    span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip { 
        display: none !important 
    }
    div.wpcf7-validation-errors,
    .highlight {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #fcf8e3;
        color: #c09853;
        border: 2px solid #faebcc;
    }
    div.wpcf7-validation-errors {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #d6e9c6;
        background-color: #dff0d8;
        color: #468847;
    }
    div.wpcf7 textarea {
        height: 110px;
    }
    div.wpcf7 input[type="submit"],
    div.wpcf7 p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't upload your entire CSS file; just the relavent parts will make it a lot easier for people to help you. Could you also provide a bit more info about what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Emily, thanks for that. Am just new to this. Am working on a wordpress theme that has no child theme. The theme has a sticky menu but the client's logo couldn't match with the dark background so I changed the menus background though when I scroll down, the menu's background is different from what I set

Answer (score 1):

just add this at the end of your themes stylesheet:

```
.navbar.fixed{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

regarding the mobile question you need to search for appropriate media query in the css and add the above to the according block.

Comment: Thank you very much Funkysoulzh, it worked. How can I make it transparent white

Comment: Though the menu bg colour on mobile shows a dark background and text

Answer (score 0):

You should provide us with some of your code to be able to help properly.. but in short

you need a scroll listener (if using jquery)

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    jQuery('.navbar-nav').addClass('redColored');
} else {
    jQuery('.navbar-nav').removeClass('redColored');
}
});
```

and the CSS

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    background:none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav.redColored{
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply funkysoulzh, am using css

Comment: Kelvin I've updated my answer to reflect your css / html, but you probably understand the solution with the code above

Comment: oh yes, I made the changes but no change. Changes can only be reflected when I use custom css.

Comment: did you add the above in your child theme?

Comment: The theme am using has no child theme

Comment: Hi funky, what should I do, am really stuck

Comment: can you post the URL to your site?

Comment: Here it is www.kloosup.nl

Comment: ok so what would you like to have? when not scrolled something else than white? and when scrolled something else than gray?

Comment: When scrolled something other than grey.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough example but hopefully you get the concept. You can a class to the header once it has scrolled.

Any styling changes to that class like the color are defined in your css but you will need some simple JS to detect your scrolling. Please see this example (I took my own liberties with the styling like the height changing) and customize to your needs

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 97) {
            $("header").addClass('shrink');
        } else {
            $("header").removeClass("shrink");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 900px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
}

header.shrink {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

h1.shrink {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="container">
<header><h1>I'm a header</h1></header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the issue is I don't really know which code I should put where. Am kind of new to this